# ¿Cómo puedo implementar un algoritmo de ordenación topologica en mi código de grafos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Alguien me podría asesorar en como se puede modificar el código para que lo ordene en forma topológica, es decir ordenarlo al tiempo de término, ya sea de forma ascendente o descendente.

Este es el código:

```
class Vertice:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.nombre = n
        self.vecinos = list()

        self.d = 0
        self.f = 0
        self.color = 'white'
        self.pred = -1

    def agregarVecino(self, v):
        if v not in self.vecinos:
            self.vecinos.append(v)
            self.vecinos.sort()
class Grafo:
    vertices = {}
    tiempo = 0

    def agregarVertice(self, vertice):
        if isinstance(vertice, Vertice) and vertice.nombre not in self.vertices:
            self.vertices[vertice.nombre] = vertice
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def agregarArista(self, u, v):
        if u in self.vertices and v in self.vertices:
            for key, value in self.vertices.items():
                if key == u:
                    value.agregarVecino(v)
                #if key == v: #Se comenta porque es grafo dirigido
                 #   value.agregarVecino(u)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def imprimeGrafo(self):
        for key in sorted(list(self.vertices.keys())):
            print("Vertice: "+key )
            print("Descubierto/termino: "+str(self.vertices[key].d)+ "/"+ str(self.vertices[key].f))

    def dfs(self, vert):
        global tiempo
        tiempo = 0
        for v in sorted(list (self.vertices.keys())):
            if self.vertices[v].color == 'white':
                self.dfsVisitar (self.vertices[v])

    def dfsVisitar(self, vert):
        global tiempo
        tiempo = tiempo + 1
        vert.d = tiempo
        vert.color = 'gris'

        for v in vert.vecinos:
            if self.vertices[v].color == 'white':
                self.vertices[v].pred = vert
                self.dfsVisitar(self.vertices[v])
        vert.color = 'black'
        tiempo = tiempo + 1
        vert.f = tiempo

class Controladora:
    def main(self):
        g = Grafo()
        a = Vertice('U')
        g.agregarVertice(a)

        for i in range(ord('U'), ord('[')):
            g.agregarVertice(Vertice(chr(i)))

        edges = ['UV','UX','VY','YX','XV','WY','WZ']   
        for edge in edges:
            g.agregarArista(edge[:1], edge[1:])
        g.dfs(a)
        g.imprimeGrafo()   

obj = Controladora()
obj.main()
```

Esto es lo que muestra al correrlo:

> Vertice: U
>   Descubierto/termino: 1/8
>   Vertice: V
>   Descubierto/termino: 2/7
>   Vertice: W
>   Descubierto/termino: 9/12
>   Vertice: X
>   Descubierto/termino: 4/5
>   Vertice: Y
>   Descubierto/termino: 3/6
>   Vertice: Z
>   Descubierto/termino: 10/11

En fin, lo que quisiera implementar es que coloque el vértice `W` como el primero después el vértice `Z` y por consiguiente el vértice `U` y asi sucesivamente puesto que es en tiempos de término. Sin mas que decir, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal tu problema tal y como tienes el código con `d` y `f` calculadas  lo único que te faltaria es básicamente ordenar un diccionario de objetos según uno de sus atributos para poder imprimirlos. Mas concretamente quieres ordenar los objetos `Vertice` contenidos en `self.vertices` según su atributo `f`.

Pues lo más simple es usar la función preconstruida [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), para pasarle la key apropiada hay dos métodos:

- Usar una función lambda:

  ```
  for nombre in (sorted(self.vertices, key = lambda nombre: self.vertices[nombre].atributo, reverse= invertida)):
      print("Vertice: {}".format(nombre))
      print("Descubierto/termino: {}/{}".format(self.vertices[nombre].d, self.vertices[nombre].f))
  ```
- O mejor aún, hacer uso de la buena y documentada biblioteca estándar de Python y usar [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter). Esto además nos permite crear un método por si queremos enun futuro ordenar por cualquier otro atributo (tanto en orden ascendente como descendente):

  ```
  def imprimeOrdenado(self, atributo, invertida = False):  
      for vertice in (sorted(self.vertices.values(), key=operator.attrgetter(atributo), reverse= True)):
          print("Vertice: {}".format(vertice.nombre))
          print("Descubierto/termino: {}/{}".format(vertice.d, vertice.f))
  ```

  El método recibe dos parámetros, el primero es el atributo por el que quieres ordenar pasado como una cadena. Si quieres que lo ordene de mayor a menor le pasas el segundo parámetro `invertida` como `True`, si quieres que sea de menor a mayor se lo pasas como `False` o no se lo pasas. Recuerda importar el módulo al inicio de tu script

  ```
  import operator
  ```

En tu código puede quedar así:

```
import operator

class Vertice:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.nombre = n
        self.vecinos = list()

        self.d = 0
        self.f = 0
        self.color = 'white'
        self.pred = -1

    def agregarVecino(self, v):
        if v not in self.vecinos:
            self.vecinos.append(v)
            self.vecinos.sort()
class Grafo:
    vertices = {}
    tiempo = 0

    def agregarVertice(self, vertice):
        if isinstance(vertice, Vertice) and vertice.nombre not in self.vertices:
            self.vertices[vertice.nombre] = vertice
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def agregarArista(self, u, v):
        if u in self.vertices and v in self.vertices:
            for key, value in self.vertices.items():
                if key == u:
                    value.agregarVecino(v)
                #if key == v: #Se comenta porque es grafo dirigido
                 #   value.agregarVecino(u)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def imprimeGrafo(self):
        for key in sorted(list(self.vertices.keys())):
            print("Vertice: "+key )
            print("Descubierto/termino: "+str(self.vertices[key].d)+ "/"+ str(self.vertices[key].f))

    def imprimeOrdenado(self, atributo, invertida = False):  
        for vertice in (sorted(self.vertices.values(), key=operator.attrgetter(atributo), reverse= True)):
            print("Vertice: {}".format(vertice.nombre))
            print("Descubierto/termino: {}/{}".format(vertice.d, vertice.f))

    def dfs(self, vert):
        self.tiempo = 0
        for v in sorted(list (self.vertices.keys())):
            if self.vertices[v].color == 'white':
                self.dfsVisitar (self.vertices[v])

    def dfsVisitar(self, vert):
        self.tiempo += 1
        vert.d = self.tiempo
        vert.color = 'gris'

        for v in vert.vecinos:
            if self.vertices[v].color == 'white':
                self.vertices[v].pred = vert
                self.dfsVisitar(self.vertices[v])
        vert.color = 'black'
        self.tiempo += 1
        vert.f = self.tiempo

class Controladora:
    def main(self):
        g = Grafo()
        a = Vertice('U')
        g.agregarVertice(a)

        for i in range(ord('U'), ord('[')):
            g.agregarVertice(Vertice(chr(i)))

        edges = ['UV','UX','VY','YX','XV','WY','WZ']   
        for edge in edges:
            g.agregarArista(edge[:1], edge[1:])
        g.dfs(a)
        g.imprimeOrdenado('f', invertida = True)   

obj = Controladora()
obj.main()
```

Lo que nos da una salida:

> Vertice: W
>   Descubierto/termino: 9/12
>   Vertice: Z
>   Descubierto/termino: 10/11
>   Vertice: U
>   Descubierto/termino: 1/8
>   Vertice: V
>   Descubierto/termino: 2/7
>   Vertice: Y
>   Descubierto/termino: 3/6
>   Vertice: X
>   Descubierto/termino: 4/5

`sorted` retorna una lista que contiene los objetos `Vertice` ordenados. Puedes obtener la lista en vez de usarla en el `for`:

```
listaVerticesOrd = sorted(self.vertices.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('f'), reverse= True)
```

Creo que es esto lo que deseas, `self.vertices` lógicamente no se puede ordenar porque no tiene orden intrínseco al ser un diccionario.